# Can an iPhone run two operating systems?

Tags: ios, virtualization, iphone

I'm looking for something similar to Virtualbox, but in iOS where each system would be isolated. The content in the virtual environment shouldn't be detectable by the host. *(Not restricting answers to un-jailbroken iOS devices)*

Comment: `The content in the virtual one should not be detected by the main host.` This seems impossible to me.
The host decides everything when it comes to resource control like Memory.
If you have access to a host, there are means to access all VM's on that machine by definition. (Like dumping the ram of the host).

Comment: Sorry i am new to here, totally don't know how to reply to you. Actually I am just thinking of the similar question like this post  [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/194353/police-forcing-me-to-install-jingwang-spyware-app-how-to-minimize-impact)

Comment: No problem, you replied correctly :-) I think your terminology made me jump to wrong conclusions. In virtualization, you have 1 physical machine that can run multiple virtual machines. However, if the physical machine (host) gets infected with something, both virtual machines can be manipulated through the infected host. Dual booting might be an option, allthough I'm not sure this will serve the full isolation that you're looking for. As both rom's can be seen by the actual hardware in order to be able to boot from both of them.